# calculating the percentage based on the number of records in the crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my Crystal Reports I have a field called "PAYMENT", it has to be displayed according to the following requirement.

- If there is only one RECORD in detail section then it has to display:

  ```
  PAYMENT=percentage
  ```
- If there are MULTIPLE RECORDS in detail section then it has to display:

  ```
  PAYMENT=percentage+(percentage(total value)+remarks)
  ```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula in CR to count the records

**CountRecords**

```
Count ({Table.PAYMENT})
```

**PaymentDisplay**

Then create another formula with your decision making:

```
If COUNT FORMULA = 1 then DISPLAY OPTION 1 else DISPLAY OPTION 2
```

I have not tested this but it should work.